# How to integrate templates into Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am new to Codeigniter. How do you integrate templates? Something like:

header_template.php etc...

Right now I do it like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Page extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {   
        $this->load->view('head_template.php');
        $this->load->view('header_template.php');
        $this->load->view('navigation_template.php');
        $this->load->view('page_view.php');
        $this->load->view('footer_template.php');

    }
}
```

While this is fine, there has to be a better way. I have to include this into every controller, which is a little bit intimidating.

I know about the template engine, but it's not what I am looking for. Plus, it says it's slow in the Codeigniter documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this temple engine](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/index.html) very easy and good documentation too

Check this git repo for sample application with CI and templete engine

[github.com/mrsrinivas/ci_template](http://github.com/mrsrinivas/ci_template)

Comment: Is there a simple tutorial for the template engine besides the user guide? I am having difficulty understanding how to simply get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public function index()
{   
    $data["header"]     = $this->load->view('head_template.php',"",true);
    $data["navigation"] = $this->load->view('navigation_template.php',"",true);
    $data["footer"] = $this->load->view('footer_template.php',"",true);
    $this->load->view('page_view.php', $data, false);
}
```

inside your "page_view.php"

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  echo $header;
  echo $navigation;
  echo $footer;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

More information you can find at -http://www.codeignitor.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Code included for just a sample for template inclusion-

```
class Template extends CI_Controller{

 public function __construct(){
    parent :: __construct();
}

/**
 * TODO: Get the template from database or some configuration file
 * 
 * 1) Get Template hook
 * 2) Get Header
 * 3) Get Footer
 * 4) Get other hooks
 */
public function loadTemplate($viewName, $headerData = "", 
                            $viewData="", $footerData=""){
    $headerData["userId"] = (is_numeric($this->CI->session->userdata("userId")))
                            ? $this->CI->session->userdata("userId") : null;                            
    $this->CI->load->view('header/header', $headerData);
    $this->CI->load->view($viewName, $viewData);
    $this->CI->load->view('footer/footer', $footerData);
}
}
```

// Template class end with further code

```
// Login.php that extends template class
class Login extends Template {
  public function Login() {
    parent :: __construct();
}

  public function getUserDetails(){
    $userDetails = $this->loadTemplate("myDataNeedToshow");

}
}
```

Comment: For this problem you need to extend CI_Controller class or other way round is create your own class with extending of CI_Controller class and extend your each controller with your extended class. If you want i can provide you an example.

Comment: I would appreciate an example, if possible.

Comment: i have included some code snippets (this is just a sample not an actual code), you need to update the code (according to your need).

Comment: Thank you, I will use what you have provided.

Comment: @Rasteril I don't want to confuse you but you might decide to use Smarty. In that case you can use the {include} tag in your views. 

If you like, I made a Spark for Plenty Parser which is going to ease the inclusion process https://github.com/damko/Plenty-Parser/tree/spark

Answer (score 0):

That template engine listed by the previous commenter was nice, but has not been updated in quite a while and may be overkill for what your objective is.

While that may work, I believe [this very simple layout library](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/layout-library) is what you're looking for.

It's very very basic, but gets the job done. I've extended it in the past to allow multiple "content sections" with ease, but I usually use it just to get the html headers and footers in there quickly.

Answer (score 0):

what i do is have a file called template.php in the views folder that looks like this:

```
views/template.php:
<?= $this->load->view('header_view');?>
<?= $this->load->view($load_page);?>
<?= $this->load->view('footer_view');?>
```

then in the controller i call it like this:

page.php:

```
$page = array(
        'meta_title' => 'Register Package',
        'load_page' => 'package_view'
        );
        $this->load->view('template', $page);
```

i'm sure there is a better way but i'll look into it when i get time

Comment: Wow, this is very simple and exactly what I need. With a bit of customization, I will implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Helpers can help you have a clean integration.
Sample code of mine:

[Helper Functions](https://github.com/hashimi/onlineBook/blob/master/application/helpers/template_helper.php)

[Controller](https://github.com/hashimi/onlineBook/blob/master/application/controllers/admin/home.php)